# How do you clear the datebox value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datebox

How do you clear the `datebox` value?
On load my `datebox` has the following data by default:
`"01/01/0001 00:00:00"`

From View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @id = "date", @name = "date", @data_role =     "datebox",@value="", @data_options = " {'mode':'calbox' }", @onload="this.value='';" })
```

From Controller:

Comment: Can you post your controller code as well?

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
         return View(new EntitiesModel());
        }
From Model:
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a date")]
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to have an empty string in the textbox if the value is not given yet then you have to use Nullable DateTime in the Model:

```
class Model {
  public DateTime? Date { get;set; }
}
```

The call in the view remains the same:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for that:

```
$(function(){
  $("#date").text("");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#Date").val("");
     });
```

Note: better if u set the datetime value to current datetime in ur model, or else make it nullable and set it to null (or dont set it)